# How to handle unix paths (\) with node?

Tags: node.js, unix

I have an array like this:

```
var array = ['File Name', ...]
```

I'm executing unix commands like this:

```
for (const item of array) {
   execSync(`convert -trim ./original/${item}.png ./trimmed/${item}.png`)
}
```

Here I get an error because unix format spaces like this `File\ Name`. So, in my code, the script can't file the original file.

What is the usual way to handle this?

Comment: You can surround the name with quotes. It's the usual way to handle spaces in the path.

Comment: @VLAZ Could you give me an example?

Comment: `execSync(\`convert -trim "./original/${item}.png" "./trimmed/${item}.png"\`)`

Comment: @VLAZ Damn, the solution was so simple ... could you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid problems with spaces, you can simply surround the full path in double quotes. It's a very common way for the shell to handle spaces in paths:

```
execSync(`convert -trim "./original/${item}.png" "./trimmed/${item}.png"`)
```

The other way of handling spaces is to escape them but it gets ugly as you also need to escape the escapes, if you don't need a space. It also makes reading the path really hard when debugging and overall it's probably not worth the hassle.